# Asp.Net, SQL and TimeZones

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, timezone

It's been asked, but I am battling to grasp the concept of how to handle timezones in a web app. I have a system that tracks the progress of projects. I have a ProjectStartDate DATE in my SQL Server database. (There's a few more fields and tables, but lets focus on one).

The server is located somewhere in the United States. I live in Australia.

Calling `SELECT GETDATE()` returns "2013-08-11 14:40:50.630"
My system clock shows "2013-08-12 07:40"

In my database, I have 'CreateDateTime' columns on all tables. When I store that, within my c# code, I use `CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow`

I use that, as I heard it was better to use UTC.

But, when a user is presented with a calendar control, and they select a Start Date for a project, I store what ever the user selected. No conversion... And as I said, the StartDate is a DATE type in the database.

The problem is, if a project started today - my front end says that the current project is No Started, because the server is still in Yesterday.

I think the dates should be stored as I am storing them. But maybe I need to somehow get the users timezone, and apply that on the UI level?

Problems I see are:

- I don't know the users timezone. Add something to allow them to select it?
- The status of the project maybe determined in a stored procedure, so when can I apply the conversion? In the proc, it might do a check, and return a VARCHAR stating "Not Started" if the StartDate <= DateTime.Now?

I use EntityFramework and Linq to get data most of the time. I need a strategy for inserting and retrieving data, both from a  SQL sense, and a .Net sense.

I have added code to get the user to select their timezone based on this:

```
public List<TimeZoneDto> GetTimeZones()
{
    var zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    var result = zones.Select(tz => new TimeZoneDto
        {
            Id = tz.Id, 
            Description = tz.DisplayName
        }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

That is then persisted in their profile.

All dates are being stored as UTC, as advised in the answers below.

I'm still confused how to handle the dates when they go to and from the database, to the client. Here is an example of how I am storing a record:

```
public int SaveNonAvailibility(PersonNonAvailibilityDto n)
{
    person_non_availibility o;

    if (n.Id == 0)
    {
        o = new person_non_availibility
            {
                PersonId = n.PersonId,
                Reason = n.Reason,
                StartDate = n.StartDate,
                EndDate = n.EndDate,
                NonAvailibilityTypeId = n.NonAvailibilityTypeId,
                CreateUser = _userId,
                CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow

            };
        _context.person_non_availibility.Add(o);
    }
    else
    {
        o = (from c in _context.person_non_availibility where c.Id == n.Id select c).FirstOrDefault();
        o.StartDate = n.StartDate;
        o.EndDate = n.EndDate;
        o.Reason = n.Reason;
        o.NonAvailibilityTypeId = n.NonAvailibilityTypeId;
        o.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        o.LastUpdateUser = _userId;
        o.Deleted = n.Deleted ? DateTime.UtcNow : (DateTime?)null;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return o.Id;
}
```

This method basically saves when a person is not available for work. Note the way I store the LastUpdateDate. Also, the 'Start' and 'End' dates. Those dates are more 'Business' dates.

On selection, and then date checking, is where I have issues. In this example, I am getting a persons rate of charge, based on NOW.

```
public decimal CurrentRate
{
    get
    {
        if (ResourceCosts != null)
        {
            var i = ResourceCosts.FirstOrDefault(t => DateTime.UtcNow <= (t.EndDate.HasValue ? t.EndDate.Value : DateTime.UtcNow) && DateTime.UtcNow >= t.StartDate);
            if (i != null) return i.Cost;
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So, what I am wanting to do here, is, based on the current date, I want to see his rate (As his charge our rate maybe be $100 from the 1st Jan, to the 15th Jan, and then $110 from the 16th until the 31st of Jan. So, I look for the rate applicable today (if any). This doesn't work across time zones, and it's maybe here where I need to do some date manipulation based on the 'DateTime.UTCNow'?

Note, I now know the users timezone based on the code above where I am storing his timezone. I can use that somehow here? Maybe, when the user logs in, grab the date info from his profile (Zimezone info), and then have a global shared function, that returns the users datetime, based on adding or removing hours from the UTC Date... and using that where ever I am doing DateTime.UTCNow?

Hope someone can guide me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may find that there is not one single "right" way to handle all of this.  There are multiple approaches to the several different problems you describe in your question. I will attempt to clarify a few points.

- First, don't ever attempt to think about *local time* on a server.  Your code and data should not have to change based on where you deploy it.  You said your server was in the USA, but there are multiple time zones to consider, and many servers will have their time zone set to UTC regardless of their physical location.

  You should avoid `GETDATE()` or `SYSDATETIME()` in SQL Server.  If you need a current timestamp in SQL, use [`GETUTCDATE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) or [`SYSUTCDATETIME()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx).  If for some reason the server's time zone is important to you, use [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx) instead.

  Likewise, avoid using `DateTime.Now` in .Net from any server-side code.  Use [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) or [`DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcnow.aspx)  for a UTC timestamp, or use [`DateTimeOffset.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.now.aspx) if for some reason the server's time zone is important to you.

  You can read more about this in my blog post: [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)
- Next, let's talk about the data type you're using.  The `date` type in SQL Server stores just a date. That's it.  No time, no offset, and no time zone.  An example would be `2013-08-11`.  You should use it when you really mean a whole *calendar date*.  There is no worldwide uniform context of "today".  Instead, everyone has their own meaning based on their time zone.  Also, not every calendar day is 24 hours in length.  A day could be 23, 23.5, 24, 24.5 or 25 hours long, depending on how daylight saving time is applied in the particular time zone, and if you are evaluating the day of a DST transition.

  In .Net - there is no `Date` type, so a SQL `date` is converted to a `DateTime` with the time set to midnight (`00:00:00`), and the kind set to `Unspecified`.  But don't fool yourself - the time isn't suddenly midnight, we are just filling in zeros for the time.  This can lead to a lot of error and confusion.  (If you want to avoid that, you can try [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which has a `LocalDate` type for this purpose.)
- What you really need to be thinking about, and haven't defined in your question, is this:

  > **What *exact* moment does a project start?**

  Right now you are just saying `2013-08-11`, which doesn't refer to a specific moment in time.  Do you mean the beginning of that day in a *particular* time zone?  Or do you mean the beginning of that day according to the *user's* time zone?  Those might not be the same thing.  You can't compare to anyone's "now" (utc, local, or otherwise) unless you know what moment in time you are talking about.

  If the project starts at an exact moment in time worldwide, then the easiest thing would be to store a `datetime` (or `datetime2`) type that contains that precise time in UTC.  So you might say that a project starts at `2013-08-10T14:00:00Z` - which would be exactly midnight on August 11th in Sydney, Australia.  In .Net, you would use a `DateTime` type with the `.Kind` set to `Utc`.

  Another way you could represent this is by storing a `datetimeoffset` type that has a value of `2013-08-11T00:00:00+10:00` - which is the same moment in time, but uses the offset to give you a value that is pre-converted.  (Sydney is at UTC+10 on that date).  You would use the `DateTimeOffset` type to work with this in .Net.

  But if the project starts at different times depending on the user, then it's not really an exact moment in time.  It's more of a "floating" start.  If users from different places around the world are assigned to the same project, then some users could be starting before others.  If that's your intention, then you can just use the `date` type if all projects start at midnight, or you can use a `datetime` or (`datetime2`) type if projects might start at different times.  In your .Net code, you would use a `DateTime` type with the `.Kind` set to `Unspecified`.
- With regard to getting the user's time zone, the best thing you could do would be to ask them.  Despite the common misconception - you can't just get it from the browser.  All you could tell from the browser is what their *current* offset is.  (Read the "TimeZone != Offset" section of the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)).

  When asking the user for their time zone, if you decide to use Windows time zones you can produce a dropdown list from the [`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx) method.  The `.Id` is the key you store in your database, and you show the `.DisplayName` to the user.  Later you can use the [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx) method to get a [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) object that you can use for conversions.

  If you wanted to be more precise, you could use IANA time zones instead of the Windows time zones.  For that, I recommend using a map-based timezone picker control, such as [this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).  You might also use [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) to guess a default value for your control.  On the server you would use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) to perform time zone conversions.
- There is an approach that doesn't require time zone conversions.  Basically, you do *everything* in UTC.  That includes transmitting the time to the browser in UTC.  You can then use JavaScript to get the user's current time *in UTC* and compare against that.

  You can use various functions of the JavaScript `Date` class to do this if you wish.  But you may find it easier to work with a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

  While this approach is viable for many things, security is not one of them.  Your user can easily change the clock of their computer to work around this.
- Another approach would be to compare server-side against UTC.  If you have the exact UTC starting time in your database, then you can just check `DateTime.UtcNow` in your .Net code and use that to decide what to do.  You won't need the user's time zone to make this comparison, but you will need it if you want to show them what that means in their local time.

I hope this clears up the confusion and didn't make it worse! :)  If you have additional concerns, please edit your question or ask in comments.

**UPDATE**

In response to your updated question, I suggest you try the following:

```cs
var timeZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time"; // from your user's selection
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
var nowInTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, timeZone);
var todayInTimeZone = nowInTimeZone.Date;

var i = ResourceCosts.FirstOrDefault(t => t.StartDate <= todayInTimeZone &&
            (!t.EndDate.HasValue || t.EndDate >= todayInTimeZone));
```

Of course this means that in your `StartDate` and `EndDate` fields, you are not storing these as UTC - but rather as the "business dates" that are relevant to the user.  These only line up to a specific moment in time when you apply a time zone, so the same UTC timestamp could fall on different dates depending on what the user's time zone is.

Also, you are using fully inclusive ranges, which is usually OK for these kind calendar date ranges.  But make sure you realize that there could be overlap.  So if you have `2013-01-01 - 2013-02-01` and `2013-02-01 - 2013-03-01`, then there is that one day `2013-02-01` that is in *both* ranges.

A common way around this problem is to use half-open intervals, `[start,end)`.  In other words, `start <= now && end > now`.  But this is more common when using a full date and time instead of just a date.  You might not need to do this, but you should at least think about it for your particular scenario.

Comment: This looks to be a fantastic answer, Matt. A lot to think about. Still reading, with the links as well. Once I have digested it, I'll probably fire a few more questions. Thanks!

Comment: I've now modified my question, based on some things you said. As for the Date vs DateTime... I am trying to portray that dates are inclusive. That is, 01-01-2013 to 02-02-2013 = 24 hours. 01-01-2013 to 01-01-2013 = 24 hours.

Comment: In your updated code, I see four fields that will all be `DateTime` in .Net.  Of those, `CreateDate` and `Deleted` should be a `datetime` or `datetime2` in SQL Server and stored as UTC.  `StartDate` and `EndDate` can be just a `date` if you want, but you need to decide exactly what you want to do.  There is no one right answer - it depends entirely on your specific business requirements.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Indeed, the Created, Updated and Deleted columns are all DATETIME - I refer to those as System fields, and all the Start/End dates are DATE types, which are more Business fields. The part I am stuck on is where I need to work out if the person should be at work or not. I have updated the code to show how I am currently, and incorrectly, doing this check.

Comment: Does my update help you?  This is not the only approach - just one of them.  Feel free to adjust for your specifics.

Comment: Most certainly does, thanks Matt. My problem is 90 percent solved. My last remaining issue is that I use a few stored procedures. My application code is fine, but I need to handle date checks within my stored procedures now, and TimeZoneInfo isn't available to me down there.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible.  I am working on NodaTime support for SQLCLR, but its not ready yet and there is nothing built in.  TimeZoneInfo won't work there unless you run it in unsafe mode.  You will have to do all time zone conversions in your application code.

Comment: For example, you could do the first part of my example and then pass `todayInTimeZone` into the stored proc as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a user's timezone from the browser. This will only get the value that they've set on their computer.  So they can manipulate this for their advantage. For example, if you were limiting access until midnight local time, they could change their time to get "early" access.  So keep that in mind.

Next what you'll want to do is store all times in UTC in the database. Instead of using GetDate() you can use GetUTCDate().

Next, you can either store their timezone, or their offset from UTC in the database.  You get into some danger just storing the UTC offset, because timezones that observe daylights savings will have different offsets at different time of the year.

But with these two pieces of information, you can calculate the "local" time of the user. You can either add the number of hours to your stored date, then compare that to the local server time (also adjusted from UTC.)

Of if you don't really care that much, you can store the time in UTC in the database, then simply compare DateTime.UTCNow on the server to determine if they should have access or not.